# With R and lpsolve is there a way of optimising for the best 11 elements but still pick 15 elements in total?

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm using R's lpsolve library to optimise my fantasy football team. I must pick 15 players and I am optimising for the number of points I predict each player to get in each week. The problem is that I only earn points for the first 11 players. The remaining players don't earn points unless one of my first 11 players doesn't play in which case one of my reserve players will earn points instead.

So, what I'd like to do is tell lpsolve to optimise for the best 11 players but still pick a team that includes 15 players. I currently have an R program that optimises for 15:

https://github.com/stephendeyoung/fpl-model/blob/5b7ed15224c13459cd271089d5400dfaeeb2852d/fantasy_football_optimiser/optimiser-curr-team.R#L34

How could I adjust this program to optimise for the first 11 and still include the other constraints? I imagine I may need to tweak the program to use a particular team formation such as 4-4-2, 3-5-2 etc.

Comment: Not so simple. Add a permutation of the objective function terms, order by value, and optimize for the 11 best. After linearization, this is in theory a MIP. R/LPSolve is probably too primitive to make this an easy exercise.

Comment: What is MIP? I've got around this issue somewhat by adding another constraint to lpsolve where I basically tell it to pick 2-3 reserve players and then it can optimise the rest based on that. But I'd still prefer the program to give me the most optimal set of 11 players given the 15 player constraint.

Comment: MIP=Mixed Integer Program. The type of problems that LpSolve solves.

Comment: Here is a possible formulation: http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/06/select-n-items-but-optimize-for-best-k.html

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks very much for putting this together!